# Python: Sort dict of lists by element

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I created a dict of lists as such.

```
{'chans': [['24', 'X', 'RCP', '8400.0', 'mex', '325.0K', '8', '50 1', '17', 266, **datetime.time(22, 0)**, '17', 266, datetime.time(23, 0), '00', '23', '00', 20.604799168660975, '041'], 
 ['24', 'X', 'RCP', '8400.0', 'ody', '325.0K', '4', '40 1', '17', 266, **datetime.time(17, 0)**, '17', 266, datetime.time(18, 0), '00', '18', '00', 16.31949387241184, '053'], 
 ['24', 'X', 'RCP', '8400.0', 'mro', '325.0K', '8', '50 1', '17', 266, **datetime.time(18, 0)**, '17', 266, datetime.time(19, 0), '00', '19', '00', 27.872042154574956, '074']]}
```

I need to sort this in ascending order by using the date time object (element 10 in each list). I'm stuck at determining the proper key/value. In essence, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `sort` function

There is a `sort` function (in-place) and a `sorted` function (returns list sorted). Each of these takes an optional argument called `key`, which is called on each element for comparison. In your case, you want to call `sort(dictionary["chans"])`, which will sort the lists. Since you want to sort by the 11th element in each list, you would do this:

```
sort(dictionary["chans"], key = lambda sublist: sublist[10])
```

The key takes a sublist and returns its 11th element, so `sort` is sorting the sublists by their 11th elements (the datetime).

You can make `key` whatever you want to suit your needs.

Comment: I see what is happening now, I didn't state the 'chaos' part of the dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), and just select the index of the item in the list not dict, we can't order a dictionnary,

```
from operator import itemgetter
import datetime

f = {'chans': [['24', 'X', 'RCP', '8400.0', 'mex', '325.0K', '8', '50 1', '17', 266, """datetime.time(22, 0)""", '17', 266, datetime.time(23, 0), '00', '23', '00', 20.604799168660975, '041'], 
 ['24', 'X', 'RCP', '8400.0', 'ody', '325.0K', '4', '40 1', '17', 266, """datetime.time(17, 0)""", '17', 266, datetime.time(18, 0), '00', '18', '00', 16.31949387241184, '053'], 
 ['24', 'X', 'RCP', '8400.0', 'mro', '325.0K', '8', '50 1', '17', 266, """datetime.time(18, 0)""", '17', 266, datetime.time(19, 0), '00', '19', '00', 27.872042154574956, '074']]}

sorted(f['chans'], key=itemgetter(10))
```